# Insert id in sql table based on another particular value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck in a situation wherein I have to insert id in sql table based on another particular value in another table.

**For example:**
I have one table say bookings with column *invoice_number* and another table say *invoice_hotels* with column *invoice_id*.

I am trying to insert *invoice_id* in *invoice_hotels* based on data in *invoice_number* column of *bookings* table.

I want to achieve below functionality also use MySQL squery only not PHP

- If Last value in *invoice_number* column of bookings table is 9000
  then I want to insert 9001 in *invoice_id* column of *invoice_hotels*

I know this can easily be done through PHP script but I am trying to do it with sql only.

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234763/mysql-auto-increment-based-on-column-value) but didn't understood how to use it.

Comment: get the last insert id from 1st table and add +1 to that and then insert it in the second table

Comment: How can I do it with only sql? I mean without using PHP select query.

Comment: then why you add the php tag in the question

Comment: insert  into tablename values(SELECT IFNULL(MAX(invoice_id)+1, 1) from bookings);

Comment: @GaneshSalunkhe, Have u still this problem?

Comment: Solution suggested by you will surely work for me but I am trying to do it with triggers.

Comment: If it is working then you should accept this answer, it will help to others user also..... and if you having another doubt then you should ask another question with your all requirement :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this query:

here we are geting max id for invoice_number and then will +1 increment with help of select query after that you can insert this value to another table with help of insert query.

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( field1, field2,...fieldN )                       
 VALUES((SELECT IFNULL(MAX(invoice_number)+1, 1) from bookings), value2,...valueN);
```

IFNULL(MAX,1) meaning if id is null then it will take by default id=1

**NOTE**: I'm not sure about tablename and column name so you can adjust according your requirement.